# How do you debug a PHP test file in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, xdebug

The menu option is disabled for me. I can test ok and I can debug ok, just not both together. Is it possible, or is the menu option disabled because it isn't implemented for PHP.

I'm hoping I don't need to go through the "Create Test files" procedure to enable it as I create the test files myself, rather than letting netbeans do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to debug the `*Test.php` files individually as you would the normal project. There's also a setting (at least in NetBeans 7.0) on the project's PHPUnit properties page that tells NB to run all files ending in `Test.php` as PHPUnit tests.

Comment: If I test the *Teset.php files individually, the debugger (xdebug) will stop at the first line (as I have specified), and allow stepping through until creation of my first object. Then an exception is caught in one of PHPUnit's classes. 

The option in 7.0 sounds good as I can't see how the debugger would otherwise know to call phpunit.bat. I'm still on 6.9.1. That's why that menu option "Debug Test File" looked enticing.

Comment: What's the exception you get? If it is starting the test in debug mode, it sounds like that part is working fine. Now you just need to figure out what is causing the exception. Do you get the exception when you run the test without debugging?

Comment: No, the exception didn't occur running the test without debugging. But now, as I go to find the exception I was getting, I can't reproduce it and things work as you suggested they should. I even installed Netbeans 7 and still got the exception yesterday. Haven't touched the source but now it works fine. I had a power blackout in between, maybe the reboot fixed something... If it comes back I post again. I do recall it was in Testcase.php however.

Comment: The question I had about how does Netbeans know to call phpunit.bat when debugging a test file, I guess it must just see that the file is located in the configured Test Files directory. Furthermore, I'm guessing this new option you mention in Netbeans 7 just allows files outside this Test Files directory to be debugged as test files. Thanks for your help.